# At [online service] with “chez”, “à”, or with another preposition?

Tags: grammaire, prépositions

With regards to an online service (for example, Gmail), do you use `à`, `chez` or nothing?

> Votre compte `à` Gmail a été désactivé.
>
> Votre compte `chez` Gmail a été désactivé.
>
> Votre compte Gmail a été désactivé.

Some other examples:

> Vous n'avez pas encore de compte `à` Gmail.
>
> Vous n'avez pas encore de compte `chez` Gmail.
>
> Vous n'avez pas encore de compte Gmail.

Answer (score 2):

No preposition is normally used here because Gmail is understood to be a kind of account and not a company:

> *Votre compte Gmail a été désactivé.*

With Google, that might also have been:

> *Votre compte chez Google a été désactivé.*

Using *à* wouldn't work with Gmail or Google, although we say:

> *Votre compte à la caisse d'épargne a été cloturé*.

Answer (score 1):

I use the third option. For instance:

> Votre compte Google a été désactivé.

Ou pour éviter la voix passive :

> Votre compte Google s'est désactivé.

But I would not be surprized if I see something slightly different like

> Votre compte de Google a été désactivé.

Comment: *Votre compte de Google a été...* is very odd. What would work is *votre compte de messagerie Google a été...*.

Comment: Je l'ai vu ici : https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/40695?hl=fr Dans un autre contexte peut-être.

Comment: Je ne dis pas qu'il est impossible que quelqu'un l'écrive, simplement que la tournure est très inhabituelle et sonne mal. De plus, *compte de Google* est absent de la page du support dont tu donnes un lien.

Comment: Si vous êtes redirigé vers cette page, cela signifie que votre compte Google a été désactivé. Veuillez lire la 2e ligne.

Comment: Certes, et je n'ai rien à reprocher à cette phrase. Il n'est en revanche pas écrit *compte **de** Google*, ce qui est la forme que je conteste.

Comment: Je m'excuse vraiment. Je m'étais occupé de plusieurs tâches simultanément et je n'ai pas vu attentivement votre comment. Vous avez bien raison. Merci pour votre patience de me corriger:-)!

Comment: κανένα πρόβλημα ;-)

Comment: Wow!  C'est parfait votre grec !  Félicitations.  Malheureusement je ne possède de clavier grec pour vous répondre  en grec aussi.

Comment: @jlliagre  Voici: Να είσαι καλά!